# Aligning image in image slider for chrome only

Tags: php, html, mysql, css

I'm editing a website that contains an image slider that displays two images side-by-side, however when i view the website in chrome the images are not inline with each other like so: http://i754.photobucket.com/albums/xx182/rache_R/Untitled-1_zps6f3014ef.jpg

I use php and html to get data from a database and display the images based on the data gathered. I have tried to target the images individually in my css but it either doesn't work or effects both images.

Is there a correct way of targeting the images individually or how can i fix this?

php code:

```
<?
                $result = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM stock");
                while($obj = $result->fetch_object())
                {
                    if($obj->id&1)
                        echo "<u1>"; ?>


                    <li class="<?=$obj->orientation=='landscape'?'landscape':'portrait'?>">
                        <a href="#"><img src="./img/<?=$obj->description=='unframed'?$obj->poster_no:$obj->poster_no.'_frame'?>.jpg" alt=""></a>
                        <h4><?= $obj->description=="unframed"?"Unframed Poster - 750mm x 500mm":"Framed Poster - 790mm x 540mm"?><br />&pound;<?=$obj->price?> each</h4></li>
```

so i managed to solve it:

```
@media screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:0){
   #mi-slider li {
    vertical-align: top;
    }}
```

Answer (score 0):

Place the **< ul>** having a width so much that it can hold both images side by side and give **style='display:inline'** for the ul.. You will get the images inline

Answer (score 0):

This is more of a css question.
You have one of to options, using an inline list or a float.

personally i line inline list, you could also use a table but that is considered bad practice.
You could also use java script to calculate the position, which is also bad practice if used improperly.

W3schools.com should be a good reference if you dont know how to implement these properties in css.

Next time please replace your php with static information so it looks better :) cheers

Comment: i tried setting the css for the li class to an inline list however it had no effect on the images.

Comment: The images are also part of an image slider